# Identification of two finite fields

Tags: galois-theory, finite-fields

I got the assignment to determine the identification of $\mathbb{F}_3^2$ and $\mathbb{F}_{3^2}$. I am capable of constructing the non-prime fields $\mathbb{F}_{3^2}$ as a reduction of $\mathbb{F}_3$ by a irreducible polynomial of degree 3. By doing so I successfully obtain addition and multiplication tables.

What I do not understand is the connection between the two dimensional $\mathbb{F}_3^2$ and the one dimensional $\mathbb{F}_{3^2}$

- What does identification mean?

After having done some research I could work out the following: When constructing the finite field $\mathbb{F}_3^2$, we need to define addition and multiplication as well. While addition is trivial, multiplication seems to be a bit trickier. Therefore we somehow use the multiplication table of $\mathbb{F}_{3^2}$

- How does such "usage" look like?
- How can I multiply $\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\2  \end{pmatrix}$ by $\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\1  \end{pmatrix}$ making use of $\mathbb{F}_{3^2}$?

Can someone give me some good explanation that is suitable for a non-mathematician?

Comment: $\mathbb{F}_{3^2}$ is a two dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{F}_3$, so you'll have to explicitly write down (using linear algebra) an isomorphism between $\mathbb{F}_{3^2}$ and $\mathbb{F}_3^2$ and then define multiplication on $\mathbb{F}_3^2$ by pulling back the multiplication using the isomorphism. If you'd like me to be more explicit, let me know.

Comment: Your question is unclear. If you are asked to prove that they are isomorphic as vector fields over $\Bbb{F}_3$ then that isn't too hard once you realise that $\Bbb{F}_{3} \simeq \Bbb{F}_3[X]/(X^2+1)$. On the other hand, note that $\Bbb{F}_3^2$ is *not* a field because $(1,0)(0,1) = (0,0)$, so in this case it doesn't make sense to talk about the "identification" of two finite fields...

Comment: @Noah: Could you please point out why $\mathbb{F}_{3^2}$ is a two dimensional vector space? Maybe you mean $\mathbb{F}_3^2$?. I am pretty sure that the isomorphism between those two fields is the solution of my question. What do you mean by "pulling back multiplication". Can you be more explicit indeed? I still do not see the connection between those two fields.

Comment: @A.P: Why do you use the standard scalar multiplication? I thought to be obliged to define multiplication by somehow using the isomorphism between those two finite fields in order to get a proper field.

Comment: Because if $F$ is a field, then $F^2$ denotes either the $F$-vector space $F \times F$ or the [product $F$-algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_of_rings) $F \times F$, where multiplication is defined component-wise, which is *not* a field. The difference between $\Bbb{F}_3^2$ and $\Bbb{F}_{3^2}$ is the same as the difference between the $\Bbb{R}$-algebras $\Bbb{R}^2$ and $\Bbb{C}$: they have the same underlying vector space, but two different multiplicative structures.

Comment: But there is still an isomorphism between $\mathbb{F}_3^2$ and $\mathbb{F}_{3^2}$, though the first one is no field? I remember that this mysterious identification was used to define multiplication, because we can only use canonical addition, but it is not clear what multiplication means. If I don't mess anything up, could you show me how this works and why?

Comment: There's only a vector space isomorphism since $\mathbb{F}_{3^2}$ is a two-dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{F}_3$ (see first section of these notes http://people.csail.mit.edu/madhu/FT05/scribe/lect06.pdf), yet using this isomorphism (call it $f$), you can define a multiple low on $\mathbb{F}_3^2$ by $f(a)\cdot f(b) = f(a\cdot b)$.

Comment: Also, this may sound weird, but do you have baby Rudin? Or any book in which the complex numbers are formally defined? The complex numbers are defined as pairs $(a,b)$ of real numbers, and then you define a product on the complex numbers by $(a,b)(c,d)=(ab-cd,ac+bd)$, and then later you agree that $(1,0)=1$ and $(0,1)=i$. That is to say, you start with a vector space that is not a field, but make it into one by defining a product in a clever way. This is the spirit of the problem.